# Is it possible to change elements from the cycle slider after initiation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Cycle Slider Carousel (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php), and depending on the screen size I would have to change from 5 to 3 and then 1 slide shown (the carousel-visible option).

I know how to watch the width of the page to trigger a function to change it when falling below a threshold, but what function could I call to change the number of slides shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
     onResize();
});
$(window).load(function () {
     onResize();
});
function onResize() {
     if ($('body').outerWidth() < 640) {
         $('.slideshow').attr({'data-cycle-carousel-visible': 'number of element you want to show'});
     } else {
         if ($('body').outerWidth() > 640 && $('body').outerWidth() < 1024) {
              $('.slideshow').attr({'data-cycle-carousel-visible': 'number of element you want to show'});
         } else {
              $('.slideshow').attr({'data-cycle-carousel-visible': 'number of element you want to show'});
         }
     }
 }
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Changing the attribute after the init went through doesn't work. If only it would be this simple